# Calendar PHP MYSQL displaying events

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, web

I need help to format the code of PHP to display all of the elements such the appoint_date and client_name. My goal is to display the events in the points database such as the full details of:

```
$sql = "SELECT points.appoint_id, points.appoint_date, points.client_name, points.client_contact, points.payment_status, beauticians.b_firstname, customer.c_ref, service.service_name

FROM points 
INNER JOIN service ON service.service_id = service.service_id
INNER JOIN beauticians ON beauticians.beautician_id = beauticians.beautician_id
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.cum_id = customer.cum_id


WHERE appoint_status = 1";
```

at the moment, the purpose of the code is to display the calendar in this function.php file, I want to load all of the appointments as events to then be displayed in the calendar to edit, add, delete events in the calendar. I am having troubles to load the appointments into events unfortunately. I am, testing small queries to load.

```
<?php
/*
 * Function requested by Ajax
 */
if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
    switch($_POST['func']){
        case 'getCalender':
            getCalender($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
            break;
        case 'getEvents':
            getEvents($_POST['date']);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/*
 * Get calendar full HTML
 */
function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
{
    $dateYear = ($year != '')?$year:date("Y");
    $dateMonth = ($month != '')?$month:date("m");
    $date = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-01';
    $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N",strtotime($date));
    $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$dateMonth,$dateYear);
    $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7)?($totalDaysOfMonth):($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
    $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35)?35:42;
?>




    <div id="calender_section">
        <h2>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>');">&lt;&lt;</a>
            <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
            <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>');">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </h2>
        <div id="event_list" class="none"></div>
        <div id="calender_section_top">
            <ul>
                <li>Sun</li>
                <li>Mon</li>
                <li>Tue</li>
                <li>Wed</li>
                <li>Thu</li>
                <li>Fri</li>
                <li>Sat</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="calender_section_bot">
            <ul>





            <?php 
                $dayCount = 1; 
                for($cb=1;$cb<=$boxDisplay;$cb++){
                    if(($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay+1 || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay)){
                        //Current date
                        $currentDate = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-'.$dayCount;
                        $eventNum = 0;
                        //Include db configuration file
                        include 'dbConfig.php';
                        //Get number of events based on the current date







                        $result = $db->query(

"SELECT client_name
FROM points WHERE appoint_date


                            = '".$currentDate."' AND appoint_status = 1");
                        $eventNum = $result->num_rows;
                        //Define date cell color
                        if(strtotime($currentDate) == strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="grey date_cell">';
                        }elseif($eventNum > 0){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="light_sky date_cell">';
                        }else{
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell">';
                        }
                        //Date cell
                        echo '<span>';
                        echo $dayCount;
                        echo '</span>';

                        //Hover event popup
                        echo '<div id="date_popup_'.$currentDate.'" class="date_popup_wrap none">';
                        echo '<div class="date_window">';
                        echo '<div class="popup_event">Events ('.$eventNum.')</div>';
                        echo ($eventNum > 0)?'<a href="javascript:;" onclick="getEvents(\''.$currentDate.'\');">view events</a>':'';
                        echo '</div></div>';

                        echo '</li>';
                        $dayCount++;
            ?>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
            <?php } } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCalendar(target_div,year,month){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#'+target_div).html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        function getEvents(date){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=getEvents&date='+date,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#event_list').html(html);
                    $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        }

        function addEvent(date){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=addEvent&date='+date,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#event_list').html(html);
                    $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.date_cell').mouseenter(function(){
                date = $(this).attr('appoint_date');
                $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();
                $("#date_popup_"+date).fadeIn();    
            });
            $('.date_cell').mouseleave(function(){
                $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();        
            });
            $('.month_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
            });
            $('.year_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
            });
            $(document).click(function(){
                $('#event_list').slideUp('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}

/*
 * Get months options list.
 */
function getAllMonths($selected = ''){
    $options = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        $value = ($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i;
        $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
        $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0)).'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}

/*
 * Get years options list.
 */
function getYearList($selected = ''){
    $options = '';
    for($i=2015;$i<=2025;$i++)
    {
        $selectedOpt = ($i == $selected)?'selected':'';
        $options .= '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}

/*
 * Get events by date
 */
function getEvents($date = ''){
    //Include db configuration file
    include 'dbConfig.php';
    $eventListHTML = '';
    $date = $date?$date:date("Y-m-d");
    //Get events based on the current date
    $result = $db->query(


"SELECT client_name
FROM points WHERE appoint_date = '".$appointDate."' AND appoint_status = 1");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $eventListHTML = '<h2>Events on '.date("l, d M Y",strtotime($appointDate)).'</h2>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<ul>';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $eventListHTML .= '<li>'.$row['client_name'].'</li>';
        }
        $eventListHTML .= '</ul>';
    }
    echo $eventListHTML;
}
?>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here and not a very good description of what the problem is, specifically what you want it to do and what it's actually doing instead.

Comment: The problem is that i am struggling to load the events to be displayed in the calendar exactly with the dates, i want the calendar to display the appointments (events).

Comment: You need to boil this down to a more minimal case that reproduces the problem. In the process of doing that you might even find the source of problem itself. I can see a lot of code here, so much that's all cluttered together, so perhaps organizing it better might lead to some important discoveries. This is a stew of HTML, PHP, and SQL, there's no separation at all between these concerns.

Comment: I am unable to view function getEvents in the calendar, only to be able to display the dates without the client_name as a example.

Comment: Show the results of your query (ie what the ajax call receives). From what I can tell from your code, you aren't really doing anything with the data to put it anywhere.

Comment: ok, i cannot display the ajax call, as i am a newbie to programming

Comment: I used [Supercali PHP Event Calendar](http://supercali.inforest.com/) once for something like this. Here is a [demo](http://supercali.inforest.com/demo_calendar/) in their site.

Comment: Thank you could you please show me the example code but applied with my database queries for php